# Let $H(x)$ denote Heaviside's function. Define $F(x) := \int^x_0 H(t) \ dt$. Is $F$ continuous, differentiable? Result contrary to FTC?

Tags: real-analysis

> Heaviside's function $H(x)$ is defined as follows:
>
> $H(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$,
>
> $H(x) = \frac 1 2$ if $x= 0$
>
> $H(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$

Define $F(x) := \int^x_0 H(t) \ dt, \ x \in \mathbb R$.

$H(x)$ is continuous except at $x=0$ so the integral exists?

**Is $F$ continuous?**

I have $F(x) = x$ for $x > 0$ and $F(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$. So $F$ is indeed continuous on $\mathbb R$.

**Is F differentiable?**

According to the fundamental theorem of calculus $F^{'}(x_0) = H(x_0)$.

However now to the final question:

**Is the result contrary to the Fundamental Theorem of Analysis (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)?**

I don't see why it should be? Have I made an error?

Comment: Doesn't this affirm the FTC? The conclusion is true ($F=\int H\implies F'=H$), even if the hypotheses are not satisfied. To think that this violates the FTC would be a confusion of "if" with "if and only if".

Comment: No the function in my textbook is defined as I've wrote it.

Answer (score 4):

$F(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$. Graph the function and you'll see why.

The FTC states that if $H(x)$ is integrable, then $F(x)=\int_0^x H(t) dt$ is continuous and if $H(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $F(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

This is the case here, no contradiction.

Comment: Indeed, $F(x)$ is more than merely continuous: it is absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The left derivative of $F$ at zero is zero, the right derivative is one. Hence $F$ cannot be differentiable at zero. This is your mistake. Be careful, since the FTC requires that the function to be integrated be continuous in the whole interval.